# N3 Pie Chart changing color form controller when value changes

Tags: angularjs, n3-charts

In a site a show a n3 pie chart.

Therefore i have defined the options and data in the controller like this:

```
$scope.gdata = [{ label: "Performance", value: 0, color: "green", complementBrightness: 0, colorComplement: "black", suffix: "%" }];

$scope.options = { thickness: 8, mode: "gauge", total: 100 };
```

The data is set dynamically like this:

```
self.load = function() {
            $http.get('/api/data')
                .then(function(response) {
                    $scope.data = response.data;
                    var value = response.data.ApiApdex * 100;

                    var color = "";

                    if (value >= 90) {
                        color = "green";
                    }
                    if (value < 75) {
                        color = "red";
                    }
                    else {
                        color = "#FFA873";
                    }

                    var object = [{ label: "Performance", value: value, color: color, complementBrightness: 0, colorComplement: "black", suffix: "%" }];
                    $scope.gdata = object;
                }
        }
```

All Values are aplied, but not the color. it always shows the color it had assigned in the begining .

I Also tried to update only the value and leave one instance of the data object alive.

Same problem. the value applies but not the color 
what am i doing wrong?